# How to add Aspose in an already existing code in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, aspose

I'm implementing a game in Intellij and wanted to know, how to proof the email of one Player for correctiveness  and also send a registration mail to the Player. So I heard about aspose and find out that Intellij operates with Aspose.Emai Java for Intellij but I dont know how to add it in my existing Project. Maybe someone can help me, thanks!!
PS: I have already installed it.

Answer (score 0):

@kiko,

Aspose.Email for Java is available as downloadable JAR that you can get from its [download](https://downloads.aspose.com/email/java/new-releases/aspose.email-for-java-18.6/) section. You can then:

1. Extract the ZIP to a folder
2. Click File from the toolbar
3. Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
4. Select Modules at the left panel
5. Dependencies tab
6. '+' → JARs or directories

Once you add the JAR file, the API functionality will become available in your application for usage. You can further consult the api documentation to get further information about API functionality.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.